# Float(s) lost. \end{document} error

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\backgroundsetup{contents=name, opacity=0.2,color=black}
\begin{document}
       text
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \textbf{text}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{auc.png}
    \end{figure}
\par 
    \qquad {\textbf{OR}}
    \par 
    \textbf{text}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

So when I use these, I find that the "auc.png" leaves the box and goes to the next page. How can I put the image inside the box?

The `"Float(s) lost. \end{document} error"` is occurring at the `\end{document}` line.

Comment: you can not have a float inside a box, ie, you can;t have a figure inside tcolorbox

Comment: is there any way to put an image inside a box? additional environment or any usepackage?

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics` directly but wrapping it in `figure` explicitly says that it may be moved but that can not work inside any kind of box. Simply delete teh figure environment.

Comment: yes that worked. together with `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`

Comment: If you wanted the figure to float (and to have a caption), you would need to move the `figure` environment to enclose the `tcolorbox` instead of having the `tcolorbox` enclose the `figure`.